# Retrieve XML file from Web

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to periodically read XML files from a web server. So far, I tried two pieces of code with the same results ...

Code1

```
  Dim xRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(xSourceUrl)
  xRequest.Proxy = New System.Net.WebProxy("ourProxy:port", True)
  xRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

  Dim xResponse As WebResponse = xRequest.GetResponse()
  Dim xDataStream As Stream = xResponse.GetResponseStream()
  Dim xReader As New StreamReader(xDataStream)
  Dim xResponseFromServer As String = xReader.ReadToEnd()

  xReader.Close()
  xResponse.Close()
```

Code2

```
 Dim xWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
 xWebClient.Proxy = New System.Net.WebProxy("ourProxy:port", True)
 xWebClient.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
 xWebClient.DownloadFile(xSourceUrl, "D:\Desktop\file.txt")
```

The file I want to download is the result of a web-query, e.g.

`http://www.ceps.cz/_layouts/Ceps/_Pages/GraphData.aspx?mode=xml&from=6.5.2014%200:00:00&to=6.5.2014%2023:59:59&hasinterval=False&sol=3&lang=CZE&agr=HR&fnc=AVG&ver=RT&para1=APG&`

which downloads absolutely normally when I paste this address into Chrome. But both pieces of code get a different XML which holds some "Error" tags, i.e. I don't get what I want.

Comment: Weird, but I also got this "Error" thing via .NET and everything is alright if using browser directly, need more investigation. +1 for now.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/436092/download-file-from-sharepoint-document-library, where it mentions use of `SharePoint.dll`. Also this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470176.aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Neoliks: thank you. This basically means that without a Sharepoint Server, I have no chance, right?

Comment: No, your link is on a sharepoint server, it seems like, according to the contents of "Error" html you are getting. So you only need a sharepoint **client**. See this: [Creating a Basic SharePoint Foundation Client Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539974(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: @Neolisk: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I dont have the DLLs mentioned in the material, that are to be acquired from the Sharepoint Server.

Comment: [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

Comment: Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @Neolisk: Definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is on a sharepoint server, according to the contents of "Error" html you are getting. Check these links:

- [download file from sharepoint document library @ CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/436092/download-file-from-sharepoint-document-library)
- [How to: Access, Copy, and Move Files (Sharepoint 2010) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470176.aspx)
- [Creating a Basic SharePoint Foundation Client Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539974%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Here is where you can get SharePoint client libraries:

- [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK @ Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=35585)